# How to use wtelegramclient library in C# to sign up?

Tags: c#, telegram, wtelegramclient

I want to use wtelegramclient library to register a telegram account via api, I used to use tlshape library and it works but with wtelegramclient I don't find a support function for this.

Register an account on tlsharp:
https://tlsharp.readme.io/docs/signup-user

WTelegramClient library:
https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your Config callback provides answer for the "first_name" and "last_name" configuration, as shown in [the ReadMe example](https://github.com/wiz0u/WTelegramClient/blob/master/README.md#non-interactive-configuration)

When you call await `client.LoginUserIfNeeded()`, if the phone_number was unknown to Telegram, it will automatically proceed to the sign-up and use your first_name/last_name to register a new account for this phone number.

*(it's all explained in the ReadMe that you should fully read before using the library)*